# Kotlin: wrap ViewModel methods in objects

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

I am following an MVVM design pattern, and some of my view models end up with quite a few methods to expose livedata to activity/fragment.

I was wondering if I could "group" these getter methods somehow and I came up with this...

​

```
  class MyViewModel(private val repository: MyRepository) : ViewModel() {

    /** RAW DATA: data received directly from the api **/
    private val apiData1 = repository.getApiData1()
    private val apiData2 = repository.getApiData2()

    inner class ApiData {
        // Expose only api data 1
        fun getApiData1() = apiData1
    }

    /** UI DATA: data conveniently formatted for the UI **/
    private var uiDataA = UiFactory.buildUiDataA(apiData1)
    private var uiDataB = UiFactory.buildUiDataB(apiData2)
    private var uiDataC = UiFactory.buildUiDataC(apiData1, apiData2)

    inner class UiData {
        // Expose all ui data
        fun getUiDataA() = uiDataA
        fun getUiDataB() = uiDataB
        fun getUiDataC() = uiDataC
    }
}
```

That way if I want to access to a method I will need to instantiate a its specific wrapper.

For raw data: `viewModel.RawData().getApiData1()`

For ui data: `viewModel.UiData().getUiDataA()`

```
class MyActivity {

    val vm: MyViewModel = ... // Load view model:

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        ...
        vm.UiData().getUiDataA().observe(...)
    }
}
```

Could you tell me if this is a good approach to wrap methods? Is it a good/bad practice? Alternatives?

Thank you

Comment: Could you clarify what are return types of the repository’s and UiFactory's functions?

Answer (score 0):

There us MVI (or [MVVMI](https://proandroiddev.com/our-way-to-mvvmi-and-mistakes-we-made-when-implementing-mvvm-5f5448b5ad50) in your case) pattern that can help you group your VM's exposed data. So instead of having multiple `LiveData` you will have a State object contains all of it's row values. Kotlin's Sealed Class can help you with that:

```
sealed class UiState {
    data class Data(
        val uiDataA: Any,
        val uiDataB: Any,
        val uiDataC: Any
    ) : UiState()
    object Loading : UiState()
    data class Error(val cause: Throwable) : UiState()
}
```

In your code you are fetching data from the repository on VM init.

> /** RAW DATA: data received directly from the api **/ 
> private val apiData1 = repository.getApiData1()

I suggest you to avoid that and fetch all of the data lazily, only on view demand or do it in the background (using coroutines for example)

```
class MyViewModel(
    private val uiService: UiFactory,
    private val getRawDataUseCase: GetRawApiDataUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

    /** RAW DATA: data received directly from the api **/
    fun fetchApiData() = getRawDataUseCase() // TODO: make it async
    
    /** UI DATA: data conveniently formatted for the UI **/
    fun fetchUiData() = liveData<UiState> {
        emit(UiState.Loading)
        try {
            emit(UiState.Data(
                uiDataA = uiService.buildUiDataA(),
                uiDataB = uiService.buildUiDataB(),
                uiDataC = uiService.buildUiDataC()
            ))
        } catch (t:Throwable) {
            emit(UiState.Error(t))
        }
    }
}
```

In clean architecture functions of your `UiFactory` are basically use cases. You can split the class into a bunch of use case classes or leave it as is. In clean architecture, your `UiFactory` would be a [Service](https://medium.com/@dnsbrnd/hi-ian-thanks-for-reading-the-article-af9d163835e8) then.
[image: Clean architecture diagram]

It's a good practice to not access your repository(data layer) from your VM (presentation layer). So your domain layer will connect them and will contain 2 classes:

```
class UiFactory(private val repository: MyRepository) { //better name it UiService
    fun buildUiDataA(): Any {
        val apiData1 = repository.getApiData1()
        // conveniently format your data apiData1
    }

    fun buildUiDataB(): Any {
        val apiData2 = repository.getApiData1()
        // conveniently format your data apiData1
    }

    fun buildUiDataC(): Any {
        // you can store your apiData1 and apiData2 in this class to not duplicate
        // repository calls
    }
}

class GetRawApiDataUseCase(private val repository: MyRepository) {
    operator fun invoke() = repository.getApiData1()
}
```

Then your activity will handle state like this:

```
class MyActivity {

    val vm: MyViewModel = ... // Load view model:

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        ...
        vm.fetchUiData().observe {
            when(it) {
                is UiState.Data -> {
                    display(it.uiDataA)
                    display(it.uiDataB)
                    display(it.uiDataC)
                    //display data 
                }
                is UiState.Error -> displayError(it.cause)
                UiState.Loading -> showLoading()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Btw, [it's not the best practice to store LiveData in your repository](https://proandroiddev.com/no-more-livedata-in-your-repository-there-are-better-options-25a7557b0730) (it's not clear from your code, but I assume you store your data there).

Your approach is probably a working solution, but some platforms common practices can save you a lot of time in development. Moreover, using popular design approaches can simplify the onboarding of new members in your team :)